# Create self-signed certificate on Suse Linux 4.4

Tags: linux, encryption, ssl, certificates, suse

I try to create a self-signed certificate for a intranet.
I am following this [suse documentation](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_apache2_ssl.html#sec_apache2_ssl_certificate_custom).

It says:

> Change into the directory **/usr/share/doc/packages/apache2** and run the
>   following command: **./mkcert.sh make --no-print-directory
>   /usr/bin/openssl /usr/sbin/ custom**

So I changed into that directory but there is no file called **mkcert.sh**?

How to proceed?

I am using *Linux version 4.4.132-53-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Wed May 23 06:57:07 UTC 2018 (036cd2f)*

Comment: Just to clarify, you are on SLES 11 or openSUSE? It might be that this script is a Enterprise-only provided script.

Comment: Also, it can be done without the script. And in that case you will find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/1816774

Comment: How do I find out if I am on SLES 11 or openSUSE please? @Tim

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try locating this script using `find` or `locate` commands, but from what I see on the web this script may no longer be shipped.

The only goal of this script is to make generation of the self-signed certificate simple, but inside it will call `openssl` commands to do all the work. Therefore my recommendation is to completely abandon the idea of using some custom third-party wrappers around openssl commands and generate the certificate yourself.

There are a lot of guides around how to do it. For example [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/10176685) or find other sources by googling `generate self-signed certificate linux`. You are on `suse`, but I believe it is more or less the same procedure for all linux flavors.